# Tree Behavior gives new child lft and rght values of 0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a MPTT using the TreeBehavior in CakePHP. Tree verifies but when I add a new root node it works. When I try to add a child to that node via `$this->{Model}->save($data)` where `$data` now has the `['{Model}']['parent_id']` set, it updates the parents' `lft` and `rght` fields to accomodate a new child but the new child has `lft` and `rght` values of 0.

Any idea of where I might be going wrong?

I have tried setting the lft and rght to null as well as unsetting, to no avail.

***Model***

```
`class Image extends AppModel {

public $displayField = 'title';

    public $actsAs = array('Polymorphic', 'Tree');

    public $imageResource = false;

    // Define virtual fiels at runtime
        public function __construct($id=false,$table=null,$ds=null){
            parent::__construct($id,$table,$ds);
            $this->virtualFields = array(
                'path' => "CONCAT('db/', {$this->alias}.uuid, '.', {$this->alias}.ext)"
                );
            $categories = $this->ImageCategory->find('list', array('fields' => array('ImageCategory.id')));
            $this->order = array('FIELD('.$this->alias.'.image_category_id, '.String::toList($categories, ', ').')');
        }

    public function save($data = null, $validate = true, $fieldList = array()) {
        if($this->imageResource === false) {
            if(!$this->loadImage(APP.'webroot'.DS.$this->path)) {
                if(!$this->loadImage(APP.'webroot'.DS.'db'.DS.$this->uuid.'.'.$this->ext)) {
                    if(!$this->loadImage(APP.'webroot'.DS.'db'.DS.$data['Image']['uuid'].'.'.$data['Image']['ext'])) {
                        // Image doesn't exist so we create a new one.
                        //die('failed to load GD Library image resource');
                        //$this->saveNew($data, $validate, fieldList);
                        //$this->uses[] = 'OrigionalImage';
                        $this->loadImage(APP.'webroot'.DS.'img'.DS.'db'.DS.$this->data['Image']['uuid'].'.'.$this->data['Image']['ext']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $data['Image']['width'] = $this->getWidth();
        $data['Image']['height'] = $this->getHeight();

        $this->writeToDisk(APP.'webroot'.DS.'img'.DS.'db'.DS.$this->uuid.'.jpg');
        //pr($data);exit;
        return parent::save($data, $validate, $fieldList);
    }

    public function saveNew($data = null, $validate = true, $fieldList = array()) {
            $parentId = $data['Image']['parent_id'];
            $this->recursive = -1;
            $parentData = $this->readDataOnly(null, $parentId);
            unset($parentData[$parentData['Image']['class']]);
            if(!empty($parentData)) {

                $data = array();

                $data['Image']['parent_id'] = $parentId;

                $data['Image']['class'] = $parentData['Image']['class'];
                $data['Image']['foreign_id'] = $parentData['Image']['foreign_id'];
                $data['Image']['title'] = $parentData['Image']['title'];
                $data['Image']['alt'] = $parentData['Image']['alt'];
                $data['Image']['image_category_id'] = $parentData['Image']['image_category_id'];
                $data['Image']['image_type_id'] = $parentData['Image']['image_type_id'];

                $data['Image']['ext'] = 'jpg';

                $data['Image']['id'] = null;

                $data['Image']['uuid'] = $this->uuid = String::uuid();
                return $this->save($data, $validate, $fieldList);
            }

        return false;
    }

    public function saveToDB($data = null, $validate = true, $fieldList = array()) {
        if($this->imageResource !== false) {
            $data['Image']['width'] = $this->getWidth();
            $data['Image']['height'] = $this->getHeight();
        }

        return parent::save($data, $validate, $fieldList);
    }


    public function read($fields = null, $id = null) {
        if(parent::read($fields, $id)) {
            $this->loadImage(APP.'webroot'.DS.'img'.DS.$this->data['Image']['path']);
            return parent::read($fields, $id);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function readDataOnly($fields = null, $id = null) {
            return parent::read($fields, $id);
    }

    public function create($data = array(), $filterKey = false) {
            if(parent::create($data, $filterKey)) {
                $this->uuid = $this->data['Image']['uuid'] = String::uuid();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    }

    public function delete() {
        unlink(APP.'webroot'.DS.'img'.DS.'db'.DS.$this->data['Image']['uuid'].'.'.$this->data['Image']['ext']);
        return parent::delete();
    }

    public function loadImage($fileString) {
            if(!file_exists($fileString)) {
                throw new NotFoundException('File: "'.$fileString.'" not found');
                return false;  
            }
            //if(empty($this->ext))
            $this->ext = strtolower(pathinfo($fileString, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            // create useing the correct function
            switch($this->ext) {
                case 'jpg':
                    $this->imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileString);
                    break;
                case 'jpeg':
                    $this->imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileString);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    $this->imageResource = imagecreatefrompng($fileString);
                    break;
                case 'gif';
                    $this->imageResource = imagecreatefromgif($fileString);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotFoundException('File "'.$fileString.'" not found');
                    return false; // just in case
                    break; // just in case
            }
            imagealphablending($this->imageResource, true);
            return true;
    }

    public function handelUpload($data = array()) {
        $this->file = $data['Image']['file'];

        if ($this->file['error'] == false) {

            if(
                    $this->file['type'] == 'image/jpeg' ||
                    $this->file['type'] == 'image/jpg' ||
                    $this->file['type'] == 'image/png' ||
                    $this->file['type'] == 'image/gif'
               ) {

                $this->uuid = String::uuid();
                $this->set('uuid', $this->uuid);
                $this->ext = strtolower(pathinfo($this->file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                $this->set('ext', $this->ext);

                $fileLocation = APP.'webroot'.DS.'img'.DS.'db'.DS.$this->uuid.'.'.$this->ext;
                if (move_uploaded_file($this->file['tmp_name'], $fileLocation)) {
                    $this->loadImage($fileLocation);
                    $this->set('width', $this->getWidth());
                    $this->set('height', $this->getHeight());
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }



    public function resizeCrop($newWidth, $newHeight) {

        $origWidth = $this->getWidth();
        $origHeight = $this->getHeight();

        $origRatio = $origWidth / $origHeight;
        $desired_aspect_ratio = $newWidth / $newHeight;

        if ($origRatio > $desired_aspect_ratio) {
           /*
            * Triggered when source image is wider
            */
           $temp_height = $newHeight;
           $temp_width = (int)($newHeight * $origRatio);
        } else {
           /*
            * Triggered otherwise (i.e. source image is similar or taller)
            */
           $temp_width = $newWidth;
           $temp_height = (int)($newWidth / $origRatio);
        }

        /*
        * Resize the image into a temporary GD image
        */

        $temp_gdim = imagecreatetruecolor($temp_width, $temp_height);
        imagecopyresampled($temp_gdim, $this->imageResource, 0, 0, 0, 0, $temp_width, $temp_height, $origWidth, $origHeight);

        /*
        * Copy cropped region from temporary image into the desired GD image
        */

        $x0 = ($temp_width - $newWidth) / 2;
        $y0 = ($temp_height - $newHeight) / 2;
        $desired_gdim = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        imagecopy($desired_gdim, $temp_gdim, 0, 0,$x0, $y0,$newWidth, $newHeight);
        $this->imageResource = $desired_gdim;
        return true;
}

    public function crop($startX, $startY, $newWidth, $newHeight) {
        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image_p, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagealphablending($image_p, false);
        imagesavealpha($image_p,true);
        imagefilledrectangle($image_p, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $transparent);
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $this->imageResource, 0, 0, $startX, $startY, $newWidth, $newHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
        $this->imageResource = $image_p;
        return true;
}

public function resizePercent($percent) {

        (float)$percent = $percent/100;

        // Get new dimensions
        list($width, $height) = $this->getimageResourcesize($image);
        $new_width = $width * $percent;
        $new_height = $height * $percent;

        // Resample
        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        imagealphablending($image_p, false);
        imagesavealpha($image_p,true);
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
        $this->imageResource = $image_p;
        return true;
}

public function stream($quality = 100) {
        switch(strtolower($this->ext)) {
                case 'jpg':
                    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
                    imagejpeg($this->imageResource, null, $quality);
                    break;
                case 'jpeg':
                    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
                    imagejpeg($this->imageResource, null, $quality);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    header("Content-Type: image/png");
                    imagepng($this->imageResource, null, $quality);
                    break;
                case 'gif';
                    header("Content-Type: image/gif");
                    imagegif($this->imageResource, null, $quality);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotFoundException('File "'.$fileString.'" not found');
                    return false; // just in case
                    break; // just in case
        }
        return true;
}

public function writeToDisk($location = null, $quality = 100) {
        if(!isset($this->ext) || empty($this->ext)) $this->ext = 'jpg';
        if($location == null) $location = APP.'webroot'.DS.'img'.DS.'db'.DS.$this->uuid.'.'.$this->ext;

        switch(strtolower($this->ext)) {
                case 'jpg':
                    imagejpeg($this->imageResource, $location, $quality);
                    break;
                case 'jpeg':
                    imagejpeg($this->imageResource, $location, $quality);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    imagepng($this->imageResource, $location, (($quality-100)/10));
                    break;
                case 'gif';
                    imagegif($this->imageResource, $location, $quality);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotFoundException('File "'.$fileString.'" not found');
                    return false; // just in case
                    break; // just in case
        }

        return TRUE;
}

private function turnAlphaBlendingOFF() { imagealphablending($im, false); }


    private function getImageResourceSize() {
        $dim = array();
        $dim[] = $this->getWidth($this->imageResource);
        $dim[] = $this->getHeight($this->imageResource);
        return $dim;
    }

    public function getWidth() {
    return imagesx($this->imageResource);
}

public function getHeight() {
    return imagesy($this->imageResource);
}

public $validate = array(
    'original_image_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),

        ),
    ),
    'uuid' => array(
        'uuid' => array(
            'rule' => array('uuid'),

        ),
    ),
    'ext' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),

        ),
    ),
    'class' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),

        ),
    ),
    'foreign_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),

        ),
    ),
    'title' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),

        ),
    ),
    'image_category_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),

        ),
    ),
    'image_type_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),

        ),
    ),
    'width' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),

        ),
    ),
    'height' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),

        ),
    ),
);


public $hasOne = array(
    'OriginalImage' => array(
        'className' => 'Image',
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
                    'conditions' => array('OriginalImage.parent_id' => 'OriginalImage.id', 'OriginalImage.id' => NULL),
    ),
            'PrimaryImage' => array(
        'className' => 'Image',
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
                    'conditions' => array('PrimaryImage.primary' => 1),
    )
);


public $belongsTo = array(
    'ImageCategory' => array(
        'className' => 'ImageCategory',
        'foreignKey' => 'image_category_id'
    ),
    'ImageType' => array(
        'className' => 'ImageType',
        'foreignKey' => 'image_type_id'
    )
);
```

***Controller***

```
class ImagesController extends AppController {


public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 8,
    'order' => 'Image.created DESC',
);

public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));




public function admin_index() {
    $this->Image->recursive = 0;

            // Keywords
            if(isset($this->passedArgs['Image.search']) && $this->passedArgs['Image.search'] != '') {
                $keywords = $this->passedArgs['Image.search'];
                $this->paginate['conditions'][] = array(
                    'OR' => array(
                        'Image.title LIKE' => "%$keywords%",
                        'Image.alt LIKE' => "%$keywords%",
                    )
                );
                $this->Image->data['Image']['Search'] = $keywords;
                $title[] = __('Search',true).': '.$keywords;
            }

            // Width 
            if(isset($this->passedArgs['Image.width']) && $this->passedArgs['Image.width'] != '') {
                $width = $this->passedArgs['Image.width'];
                $this->paginate['conditions'][] = array(
                        'Image.width BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($width-5, $width+5),
                );
                $this->Image->data['Image']['width'] = $width;
                $title[] = __('Search',true).': '.$width;
            }

            // Height 
            if(isset($this->passedArgs['Image.height']) && $this->passedArgs['Image.height'] != '') {
                $height = $this->passedArgs['Image.height'];
                $this->paginate['conditions'][] = array(
                        'Image.height BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($height-5, $height+5),
                );
                $this->Image->data['Image']['height'] = $height;
                $title[] = __('Search',true).': '.$height;
            }

            // class 
            if(isset($this->passedArgs['Image.class']) && $this->passedArgs['Image.class'] != '') {
                $class = $this->passedArgs['Image.class'];
                $this->paginate['conditions'][] = array(
                        'Image.class LIKE' => $class,
                );
                $this->Image->data['Image']['class'] = $class;
                $title[] = __('Search',true).': '.$class;
            }

            $this->set('count', $this->Image->find('count'));
            $this->set('images', $this->paginate('Image', null, array('limit' => 8)));

}


public function admin_view($id = null) {
    $this->Image->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Image->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid image'));
    }
    $this->set('image', $this->Image->readDataOnly(null, $id));
            if($this->Image->data['Image']['parent_id'] == null) {
                $this->set('related', $this->Image->children($id, false, null, null, null ,1, 0));
            } else {
                $this->set('related', $this->Image->children($this->Image->data['Image']['parent_id'], false, null, null, null ,1, -1));
            }
}


public function admin_add() {
        $this->uses[] = 'Image';
            $this->Image->create();
            if($this->request->is('post')) {
                if($this->Image->handelUpload($this->request->data) && $this->Image->saveToDB($this->request->data)) {
                    // Make thumbnails
                    if(true) {
                        $newParentId = $this->Image->getLastInsertID();
                        $this->Image->read(null, $newParentId);
                        $sizes = Configure::read('Image.thumbs.'.$this->Image->data['Image']['class']);
                        $numberOfResizes = 0;
                        foreach($sizes as $w => $h) {
                            if($this->Image->data['Image']['width']!=$w && $this->Image->data['Image']['height']!=$h) {
                                $this->Image->read(null, $newParentId);
                                $this->Image->resizeCrop($w, $h);

                                $this->request->data['Image']['parent_id'] = $this->Image->data['Image']['id'];
                                if($this->Image->saveNew($this->request->data)) {
                                    $numberOfResizes++;
                                } else {
                                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('A resized image could not be saved.'));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The original image could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The image has been saved with '.$numberOfResizes.' resize(s)!'));
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'add', 'admin' => true));
            }

            $imageCategories = $this->Image->ImageCategory->generateTreeList(null,null,null,'-> ');
    $imageTypes = $this->Image->ImageType->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('imageSubcategories', 'imageTypes', 'imageCategories'));
}


public function admin_edit($id = null) {
    $this->Image->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Image->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid image'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
                if(!empty($this->request->data['Image']['file'])) {
                    $children = $this->Image->children($this->request->data['Image']['id']);
                    pr($children);exit;
        if($this->Image->handelReUpload($this->request->data) && $this->Image->saveToDB($this->request->data)) {
                        // Make thumbnails
                        if(true) {
                            $this->Image->read(null, $this->Image->data['Image']['id']);

                            foreach($sizes as $w => $h) {
                                if($this->Image->data['Image']['width'] != $w && $this->Image->data['Image']['height'] != $h){
                                    $this->Image->resizeCrop($w, $h);
                                    unset($this->Image->data['Image']['modified']);
                                    if($this->Image->data['Image']['parent_id'] == NULL) {
                                        $this->request->data['Image']['parent_id'] = $this->Image->id;
                                        if($this->Image->save($this->request->data)) {
                                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The image has been saved!'));
                                            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'add', 'admin' => true));
                                        }
                                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The image could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->Image->id));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The image could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
                } else {

                }
            }
    $imageCategories = $this->Image->ImageCategory->find('list');
    $imageTypes = $this->Image->ImageType->find('list');
            $this->request->data = $image = $this->Image->read(null, $id);
    $this->set(compact('imageCategories', 'imageTypes', 'image'));
}

public function admin_delete($id = null) {
    if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }
    $this->Image->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Image->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid image'));
    }
            $this->Image->readDataOnly(null, $id);
    if ($this->Image->delete()) {

        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Image deleted'));
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Image was not deleted'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}



    public function admin_recover() {
            $this->Image->recover('parent');
            /*
            $condidtions[] = array('Image.parent_id !=' => null);

            $this->Image->recursive = -1;
            $images = $this->Image->find('all', array('conditions' => $condidtions, 'order' =>array('Image.id'), 'fields' => array('id', 'title', 'width', 'height')));
            pr($images);

            foreach($images as $id => $title) {
                    $this->Image->readDataOnly(null, $id);
                    $this->Image->delete();
            }
             *
             */
    }

    public function admin_verify() {
        pr($this->Image->verify());
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you use TreeBehavior::recover('parent')? That is supposed to update the lft and rgt values using the parent_id field.

Comment: it is usually better to post your "actual" code instead of making sth up or abstracting your probably faulty code to some other level.

Comment: @mark I agree. I'll update the question with the relevant parts of the controller and model code.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek It works but I have to modify my save method before I do so because I extend the save method from the AppModel as you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify the `lft` / `rght` fields in your save.

#### Wrong

```
$this->save(array(
    'parent_id' => 123,
    'lft' => 0,
    'rght' => 0
));
```

#### Correct

```
$this->save(array(
    'parent_id' => 123
));
```

Dont forget to call `$this->create();` before the save.

Comment: I mentioned in my original post that I have tried it both ways. Checking with pr() that `lft` and `rght` are not set in the array right before the parent::save and $this->save